# datetime-local of angularjs does not support in mozilla firefox

Tags: html, angularjs, datetime, firefox

I am using angularjs in html page. In html page, I have to enter datetime. So i am using datetime-local. It works fine with chrome but in mozilla its comming as text field.Is there any alternate for datetime in angular-js or any other solutions?

```
//    Sample Code: 
    <div class="col-md-2 col-centered col-fixed">
                        <label for="endDate"
                            translate="release.form.endDate">endDate</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-centered col-fixed">
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="endDate"
                            ng-model="endDate" >
                    </div>

*
```

Answer (score 0):

Input types, not supported by old web browsers, will behave as input type text.

You can use bootstrap date-time picker.

https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: This is not true.  At least not in 1.5.x